# Why is the program returning the wrong answer?

Tags: c

I'm just starting out learning C so I have no idea what i'm doing. I was writing a program to add the multiples of a number together (i.e. x + 10x + 100x ...) according to a variable k. n is the number to add/multiply. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in this? with input n being 12 and input k being 3, it should output 13332 but instead outputs 13200. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int i = 0;
    int t;
    while (i < k) {
        t = n + (n * 10);
        n = n * 10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", t);
}
```

Comment: Since you're not printing n or k after the input, how do you know the answer is wrong? But more importantly, you're not initializing t, so it's starting at some random value.

Comment: Try smaller numbers and print intermediate results. This is called debugging.

Comment: Trace through it by hand, with an even smaller example. Debugging is a very important skill. The best way to learn it is through constant practice. Don't pass up an opportunity to learn how to do it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I don't see a need in initializing `t` as long as `k>0`...

Comment: I thought his t = ... was t += ..., which is probably what he meant.

Comment: `12` and `3`, it should output `1332` ? `int t;` --> `int t = 0;`, `t = n + (n * 10);` --> `t += n;` (input `13` and `4` ==> `13332`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it just lack of elementary knowledge of . It is not an programming problem only not enough reading and learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the variable `t` instead of adding to it.
Use `+=` to add the calculated amount.
You can also add only `n`, as `n * 10` would be added next iteration (if it needs to).
You should also set `t` to `0`, because currently it isn't initialized and will hold an unpredictable garbage value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int i = 0;
    int t = 0;
    while (i < k) {
        t += n; // See here?
        n = n * 10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", t);
}
```

Besides, for clarity, I'd suggest you to:

1. make variable names more descriptive - `total` instead of `t`, etc.
2. print input messages ("Please insert...") - they're better for the user and also make the use of `n` and `k` more bright, even if you don't change them to things like `amount` or `initialNumber`

Comment: Now *this* is UB, as @LeeDanielCrocker said above.

Comment: @JohnColeman I remembered something about implicit initialization to 0 in newer versions of C...

Comment: @JohnColeman I just checked. VS wouldn't compile and GCC compiles and doesn't initialize.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What's UB?

Comment: *Undefined Behavior*

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `t = n + (n * 10);`, you consider `n` twice with each run.
Just write:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int i = 0;
    int t = 0;
    while (i < k) {
        t = n + (t * 10);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", t);
}
```

Note that `t` needs to be initialized, i.e. `int t = 0`, because otherwise expression `t = n + (t * 10)` would lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: and initialize **t**